# What is champe's change / champe change swaps, fanning in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm revisiting graph theory from my own old notes and these terms are mentioned near discussion of graph coloring. More specifically, near vizing's theorem which is

$$ \Delta(G) + 1 \text{ is a sufficient number of colors for edge-coloring } G$$

I believe that I must have misheard or misspelled these terms. Simple google searches don't reveal anything either. I've noted "search extra: champe's change, champe's change swaps and fanning" so there's no context available from the sentence.

However, the following note about swapping colors in proper colorings might give more clues which I made just before this line:

> For two color classes (set of vertices associated with every color), you don't need to swap entire color classes to maintain a proper coloring, but you may also swap within components induced by the two color classes.
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> // initial coloring      // swapped 1 and 2 within one component induced 
>                          // by them. Note we didn't have to touch the two 
>                          // disconnected vertices on the right 
> 1  2   2                 2  1     2
>  \/ \ /                   \/      
>  /\ /3\       -------->   /\
> 1  2   2                 2  1     2
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of [Kempe chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempe_chain), which are a tool used in:

- some proofs of the five-color theorem for planar graphs;
- Kempe's original (wrong) proof of the four-color theorem for planar graphs;
- Maybe a few other settings as well.

Let me try to explain the idea in the context of the five-color theorem. Here, we're trying to prove that all $n$-vertex planar graphs can be vertex-colored with at most $5$ colors,  by induction on $n$.

We can show that in any planar graph, there is a vertex of degree at most $5$. If we're trying to $5$-color an $n$-vertex graph $G$, we can find a vertex $v$ with $\deg(v) \le 5$, and color $G-v$ first (by the induction hypothesis). We can extend this coloring to a coloring of $G$, by giving $v$ a color not used by its neighbors, *unless* $v$'s neighbors use all $5$ colors between them.

If $v$ has $5$ neighbors of $5$ different colors, we need to change the coloring of $G-v$ before we can complete it to a coloring of $G$. This is what Kempe chains are good for.

Suppose that two of the colors are red and yellow. We want to recolor $G-v$ so that $v$ does not have any red neighbors. To do that,

1. We take $v$'s existing red neighbor $w$, and color it yellow.
2. This may cause other conflicts, if $w$ had yellow neighbors; fix them by recoloring those neighbors red.
3. If $w$'s formerly-yellow neighbors had red neighbors of their own, those need to be recolored yellow, and so on.

We can keep going this way, no problem. The *(red,yellow) Kempe chain containing $w$* is the set of all vertices we end up recoloring this way: swapping red to yellow and vice versa.

Once we're done, we may or may not have fixed the problem of $v$ having red neighbors. Certainly, $w$ is no longer red: it's yellow now. But what if the Kempe chain we found contains $v$'s yellow neighbor? Then that yellow neighbor becomes red; $v$ still has neighbors of all five colors.

In this case, we are saved by arguing that not *all* Kempe chains can loop around in this way. For example, if the colors around $v$ go red, blue, yellow, green, purple in that order, then the (red, yellow) chain and the (blue, green) chain can't *both* loop around, because then the chains would end up crossing.

In other applications, we make different arguments.

Comment: Thanks, this was it! I can't believe is was so way off, no wonder google couldn't autocorrect it to the right thing.